# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rows' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, postgresql, relational-database, variable-assignment

i'm trying to make a database connection by an other script.
But the script didn't work propperly.

and if I do a 'print' on the rows then I get the value 'null'

But if I use a 'select * from incidents' query then i get the result from the table incidents.

import database

```
rows = database.database("INSERT INTO incidents VALUES(3 ,'test_title1', 'test',     TO_DATE('25-07-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'sector', 50, 60)")
#print database.database()
print rows
```

database.py script:

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import logfile

def database(query):
logfile.log(20, 'database.py', 'Executing...')  
con = None

try:        
    con = psycopg2.connect(database='incidents', user='ipfit5', password='test') 

    cur = con.cursor()
    #print query

    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    con.commit()


#test row does work
    #cur.execute("INSERT INTO incidents VALUES(3 ,'test_titel1', 'test', TO_DATE('25-07-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'sector', 50, 60)")

except:
    logfile.log(40, 'database.py', 'Er is iets mis gegaan') 
    logfile.log(40, 'database.py', str(sys.exc_info()))

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
return rows
```

Comment: correct the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not declaring "rows" before your "try:" block it will not be defined if there is an exception. Try putting `rows = []` above `try`.

Comment: Yeah.. we solved the "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rows' referenced before assignment" problem. Whoohoo!

Comment: Yeah thanks!! but how can I now get my query in the database?? I've also looked for indentation in my code but it seems good?

Comment: We'll it seems like you're getting an Exception. Could you print the result of that? it's the str(sys.exc_info())

Comment: Oh my.. you have lots of problems. You need `import sys` at the top of test.py.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't help you debug your program step-by-step, especially when you are making lots of really fundamental mistakes. Keep practicing and you'll get better. Google is your friend.

Comment: @patrick You need to do some tutorials/reading. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/, http://codeproject.com/, http://learnpythonthehardway.org/, http://diveintopython.net/, etc.